# Как создать хранимую процедуру для выборки через запросы из одной таблицы в БД Postgresql

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм, postgresql, хранение-данных, хранимые-процедуры

Есть таблица следующего типа:

```
Id |        Name        | ... |  ParentId
........................................
1  |        США         | ... |    NULL
2  |       Россия       | ... |    NULL
3  |     штат Айдахо    | ... |     1
4  |     штат Айова     | ... |     1
5  | Московская область | ... |     2
6  |  Тверская область  | ... |     2
7  |       Тверь        | ... |     6
8  |       Ржев         | ... |     6
...и т.д...
........................................
```

Стоит 2 задачи:

1. Получить список всех объектов, относящихся к 'родителю'.
2. Получить количество вложенных объектов для полученного списка.

Для решения данных задач было принято решение использовать хранимую процедуру.

С первой задачей проблем нет и всё решается одним простым запросом в хранимой процедуре (пример для получения объектов России):

```
BEGIN

return query

Select 
tn."Id" as id,
tn."Name" as name,
tn."ParentId" as parent_id

From public."TableName" as tn

Where ParentId = 2;

End;
```

Запрос вернёт **Тверскую** и **Московскую области**.

С первой задачей справился, но возникают проблемы со второй. Нужно выполнить здесь же второй запрос, чтобы узнать, сколько у полученных выше объектов есть своих (зависимых) объектов.

Т.е., ответ должен быть таким:

```
Id |        Name        | ... |  ParentId  |  Count
....................................................
5  | Московская область | ... |     2      |    0
6  |  Тверская область  | ... |     2      |    2
....................................................
```

Пытался самостоятельно решить данную задачу с помощью Join'ов, но знаний не хватает. Слышал про рекурсивные запросы. Думаю, возможно с их помощью можно решить мою проблему. Буду благодарен за любую помощь и наводки.

Comment: *Для решения данных задач было принято решение использовать хранимую процедуру.* Нафига? один несложный рекурсивный CTE...

Comment: @Akina Это не обязательное условие. Если можно обойтись без хранимки - это только плюс. В идеале хотелось бы реализовать это с помощью linq, но там получится запрос в запросе, что неприемлемо.

Comment: А пересчитывать надо непосредственных детей, или рекурсивно. т.е. если  будет еще 3 записи с parent_id=7 (районы Твери, скажем) то для области должно остаться значение 2 или должно быть 5 (2 области + 3 района в Твери)

Comment: @Mike Только детей надо. Если у детей будут ещё дети - они не в счёт. Т.е., если будут добавлены районы (в Твери, к примеру добавлю 4 шт), то у Тверской области будет 2 ребёнка (Тверь и Ржев), а уже при получение Твери получим 4 ребёнка (4 района города).

Comment: тогда даже рекурсия не нужна, обычный подзапрос в списке выборки. `select ..., (select count(1) from TableName X where X.parent=tn.id) from TableName as tn ...`

Comment: @Mike спасибо за подсказку! Проблема решилась.